# Problem with logarithms

Tags: algebra-precalculus

**Problem:**

Solve:

$$\frac{1}{2^x} = \frac{5}{8^{x+2}}$$

**My attempt:**

$$\frac{1}{2^x} = \frac{5}{8^{x+2}}$$

$$\Rightarrow 5 \cdot 2^x = 8^{x+2}$$

$$\Rightarrow 2^{\log_2 5+x} = 8^{x+2} $$

$$\Rightarrow (\log_2 5 + x)(\log_a 2) = (x+2)(\log_a 8)$$

And then just keep going like this, but I'm obviously wrong already as the answer is:

$$ x = \frac{\ln 5 - 9 \ln 2}{2 \ln 2}$$

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: If someone could enlarge the latex for me that would be great.

Comment: you have a good start, but you can continue better. See my solution.

Comment: You can get the larger displayed latex form by bracketing the math code between two pairs of dollar signs (insead of one pair of dollar signs). I just did this for your question.

Comment: With the content of the answers below, I'm not certain that the given answer is correct.  Is there perhaps a copying error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$2^{\log_2 5+x} = 8^{x+2}$ implies that $2^{\log_2 5+x} = 2^{3x+6}$ and so $\log_2 5+x=3x+6$. We can conclude that $x=\frac{\log_2 5-6}{2}$.

Answer (score 4):

Some of the answers don't mention that $8=2^3$.
$$
5\cdot 2^x = 8^{x+2}
$$

Remember that $8=2^3$.  So
$$
5\cdot 2^x = (2^3)^{x+2}.
$$
$$
5\cdot 2^x = 2^{3(x+2)}
$$
$$
5\cdot 2^x = 2^{3x+6}
$$
$$
5 = 2^{3x+6}\cdot 2^{-x} = 2^{2x+6}
$$
$$
\log_2 5 = 2x+6
$$
$$
-6 + \log_2 5 = 2x
$$
$$
\frac{-6+\log_2 5}{2} = x
$$

Comment: I didn't realize I could do $5 = 2^{3x+6}\cdot 2^{-x} = 2^{2x+6}$ though. Multiply by negative exponent on both sides that is to get rid of the $2^x$ on one side.

Comment: @user3200098 : What is being done is this: $2^{3x+6}\cdot 2^{-x} = 2^{\Big(3x+6\Big)+\Big(-x\Big)}$.  Then simplify $(3x+6)+(-x)$ to get $2x+6$.

Answer (score 2):

With a slight modification, we have

$$5\cdot 2^x=8^{x+2}=(2^3)^{x+2}=2^{3x+6}$$

which means that

$$5=2^{2x+6}\\
\log_2 5=2x+6\\
x=\frac{\log_2 (5)-6}2$$

Transforming to the natural logarithm would look like

$$5=2^{2x+6}\\
\ln 5=(2x+6)\ln 2\\
x=\frac{\ln 5-6\ln 2}{2\ln 2}$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT 
Use substitution to solve the equation easily $\to$ pose $2^x=t$